# Vim: Function copy

Tags: vim

Is there a command to copy a complete function?
(Not by selecting through mouse)

ex: `10yy` --> will copy `10` lines from the cursor position.
I do not know the no of lines of a function, but want to copy the entire function.

Is there any command to copy the entire function?

Answer (score 53):

This is what I do in JavaScript and PHP:

```
va{Vy
```

1. Place the cursor somewhere in my method,
2. `va{` to visually select the the code block,
3. `V` to turn the selection from character-wise to line-wise,
4. `y` to yank

If you are too deep and `va{` only selects a portion of your function you can do more `a{` until you select what you want.

Comment: `ya{` simplifies your sequence. Which works well for any brackets based language.

Comment: `ya{` only yanks the brackets and what's inside. An extra step is needed to also yank the `function myFunc(args) ` part.

Comment: Indeed, but you are supposing here that the opening bracket is on the same line as the one from the function signature.

Comment: Yes, that's how I write code. But doesn't the problem become a bit harder when the opening bracket is on the line below the declaration? Because `ya{` would still only yank `{...}` and not the declaration. If that's the goal, the problem is solved. Very easily. But if you want to yank the whole thing (`function functionName(){}`), which is what I understand the asker wants to do, `ya{` is not enough. With the opening bracket on the same line, I thought using `V` was the simplest solution. With the opening bracket on the line below maybe one could do `"xyy` on the declaration and `j"Xy%`?

Comment: In that case, you're perfectly right. And your solution is much more flexible as we can then adjust the boundaries of the function with `o` and cursor movement.

Comment: @romainl If the opening curly brace is on the line below the function signature, then the following would still work: `va{Voky`. The `o` toggles the selection cursor to the *top* of the selection, rather than at the bottom, allowing you to move the top of the selection one line up, and thus select the entire function.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using VIM, and function body in the programming language you happen to be enclosed with braces, you can just place the cursor on one of the braces and type `y%`.

Comment: If you want to get the method-declaration as well, you might want to prefix your command with a `V`, so it becomes `V%y`

Answer (score 5):

Given your function is surrounded with line breaks you can use `yip`

which will:
`y` - yank
`i` - inner
`p` - paragraph

Comment: This doesn't work if your function body contains blank lines.

Comment: this doesnt work at all, it is indeed copies current paragraph

Comment: this does not answer the question at all. If there are any empty lines, which there often will be, it fails. OP did not ask for yanking a paragraph..

Answer (score 2):

Curly-braces languages (like Java) can use the `]m` commands for navigating to functions; some filetypes also define `]]` for this. With this, you can use `[mV]My` (go to beginning of function, start linewise visual mode, go to end of function, yank).

Many filetypes also define folding of functions. With that, you can use `zCyyzO` (close all folds, yank the entire fold under the cursor, open fold).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing mine aswell.
this works with C# and Js code.

```
" copy method
nnoremap <silent> yaf ?public\|protected\|private\|function<CR>Vj%y
" copy method and paste below
nnoremap <silent> yafp ?public\|protected\|private\|function<CR>Vj%yj%o<ESC>p
" cut method
nnoremap <silent> daf ?public\|protected\|private\|function<CR>Vj%d
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there are multiple nested {} pairs in your function body, the easist way to yank full function body is to have this in your vimrc

```
nn yaf ?function<CR>$V%y<CR>
```

place cursor anywhere within the function body, press yaf then.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here's something I keep in my vimrc that works decently well for languages that wrap function bodies in curly braces or parens (Java, PHP, etc.):

```
nnoremap <silent> yaf [m{jV]m%y
```

This maps the keybinding `yaf` (yank a function), which will work from anywhere inside the function body. It works as follows:

- `[m` : goto the end of the function declaration
- `{j` : move right above one paragraph up then move down one line, this helps with multiline function declarations. `{` will work as long as your function declaration has no empty lines inside of it.
- `V]m` : start visually selecting (line-wise) and then move your cursor to the opening bracket of the function body
- `%y` : move your cursor to the closing bracket of the function body, then yank

Answer (score -1):

Place your cursor at the start point of the function, then use `yap` or `yip`.

- yip: yank inner paragraph
- yap: yank a paragraph

Comment: this does not answer the question at all. If there are any empty lines, which there often will be, it fails. OP did not ask for yanking a paragraph..